# NSMutableArray - disable reindexing on remove

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, foundation

For example I have array:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@1, @2, @3, nil];
```

Array looks like this:

```
0 => @1
1 => @2
2 => @3
```

Then I remove object at index 0

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

...and NSMutableArray automatically reindex array, so the array looks like this:

```
0 => @2
1 => @3
```

**Question:** Is it possible to disable the automatic array reindex on remove? Or is there a similar class to use instead of NSMutableArray? Thanks.

Comment: @Rob why isn't that an answer :) ?

Comment: What do you want instead of reindexing? Perhaps insert '[NSNull null]'  at the remove index instead of remove the object.

Comment: Thanks. I think that [NSNull null] will be the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have discontinuous indexes, so your best chance is to use a placeholder object to replace the removed one. Something like

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@1, @2, @3, nil];
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNull null]];
```

Now you will have

```
0 => [NSNull null]
1 => @2
2 => @3
```

so the indexing of non-null objects is preserved.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot actually remove the object from a `NSMutableArray` and not have the index updated. But you could achieve the desired effect with a `NSMutableDictionary` (where you use a `key` (which can be a `NSNumber`) rather than the `NSUInteger` numeric index of a `NSMutableArray`).

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [@{@0 : @1,
                                     @1 : @2,
                                     @2 : @3} mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"before: %@", dictionary);

[dictionary removeObjectForKey:@0];

NSLog(@"after: %@", dictionary);
```

Yielding:

```
before: {
    0 = 1;
    1 = 2;
    2 = 3;
}
after: {
    1 = 2;
    2 = 3;
}
```

Thus, instead of:

```
NSNumber *number = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

You'd use:

```
NSNumber *number = [dictionary objectForKey:@0];
```

Or, instead of:

```
NSNumber *number = array[0];
```

You'd use:

```
NSNumber *number = dictionary[@0];
```